# Why am I getting the error "Field 't_objectproperties.Notes' can't be a zero-length string"?

Tags: enterprise-architect

I have an Enterprise Architect 12 project with enabled Security and activated 'Require User Lock to Edit' option. I locked my view and then imported my C# code via Code Engineering > Import Source Directory. That worked fine so far and I then released the lock. I wanted to update my model to reflect my code changed so I applied the lock and reran Import Source Directory. It started synchronizing the objects but at some point it started popping up a message box saying

**DAO.Recordset[3315] Field 't_objectproperties.Notes' can't be a zero-length string.**

for almost every C# class it was synchronizing. What's wrong with my EA and how can I fix it? Understandably I do no want to make a clean import every time, because that would destroy my diagrams in which I have placed th eimported entities.

Comment: Run a consistency check. It looks like some of your tagged values are broken.

Comment: Running a project intergrity check indead yielded invalid tagged values. With those repaired I got a bit further (it look longer until the errors started popping up again) - but unfortunately not a solution.

Comment: Eventually you need to run the check more than once. If that does not help -> Geert's answer.

Comment: The result of the rerun of the integrity checks was "no problems found" and still in my case I get the error messages. I am convinced by now that it cannot be my fault...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like a bug that should be [reported](http://www.sparxsystems.com/support/bug_report.html) to Sparx Systems

Answer (score 0):

I tried some actions that could be useful for solving that situation, while some notes about bugs are waiting.

My situation: using Enterprise Architect's code importer, i selected the folder for source files, when import end, appears that message that you've mentioned before.

My source files were used and/or locked by SVN, so when the import starts, some files failed for import.

**My solution:** I've Moved the source files and folder structure into another folder. and then i repeated the source code import.

That worked for me.