# Which version of Access do I need in order to successfully open an Enterprise Architect 12 project file?

Tags: ms-access, enterprise-architect

I can open my Enterprise Architect 12 project file in Access 2010, but it tells me that need some older version in order to edit the schema. With Access 2010 I can only view the schema and edit the data. I would like to do that because I have some hope, that if I change the schema I might get around the possible bug described [in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33691889/why-am-i-getting-the-error-field-t-objectproperties-notes-cant-be-a-zero-len) posted by myself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

EA uses standard Jet 3.5.

I'm pretty sure you can edit it with MS Access 97 as this [MS KB article](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/172733) suggests.

You could upgrade to Jet 4.0 as well. In that case you need to set the option to use Jet 4.0 in the Tools|Options section, and download the [Jet 4.0 EAbase.eap](http://www.sparxsystems.com/bin/EABase_JET4.zip) file from the Sparx Systems website.

AFAIK you can edit Jet 4.0 with more recent versions of MS Access.

All this said, I doubt changing the database structure will solve the issue you are having, and I think its a bad idea in general.

Comment: You don't mean changing to Jet4 is a bad idea, do you? Jet4 solves quite some UTF8 issues.

Comment: @ThomasKilian No, how did you get that idea?

Comment: Got your last sentence wrong (I missed the "structure"). My bad :-(